# unexpected network error while reading SocketChannel

Tags: java, tcp, nio

I am writing a web server by NIO. I am kind of completed the implementation but in the mean while i have one doubt on the following code snippet:

```
private void readDataFromSocket(SocketChannel socketChannel) throws IOException {   
        BUFFER.clear();
        int count = 0;
        while ((count = socketChannel.read(BUFFER)) > 0) {
            BUFFER.flip();
            int limit = BUFFER.limit();
            while (limit > 0) {
                System.out.print((char) BUFFER.get());
                limit--;
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        if (count < 0) {
            System.out.println("closing the socket!!!");
            socketChannel.close();
        }
    }
```

My assumptions is if the client closes the socket then the read (`socketChannel.read(BUFFER)`) will give me `-1`. Is my assumption correct?

2nd question:
suppose client sent me :

send: `abcdef`

send: `adnvjvnfkjnvkj`

than it was sending "`sfnskdlfnsdknfsdkj`" some network error happened. so what the server will get?

My assumption is server will get :

```
abcdef

adnvjvnfkjnvkj
```

than the server will get an error. Am i correct or server may get half data e.g. `sfnskdlfn` than error? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Correct. If the peer closes the connection, read() returns -1.
2. It's impossible to say. The data could get buffered at the sender in any way, or sent a byte at a time, or anything in between. The boundaries between what was written by each write() are not preserved. You could get nothing, or everything, or anything in between.

Answer (score -1):

Question 1: according to [the SocketChannel documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html#read%28java.nio.ByteBuffer%29) you'll get a ClosedChannelException.

Question 2: your server will buffer data right until the error happens and if it happens in the middle of the client writing, then it will contain half the data. This is assuming there is no buffering in the client before sending data, but in the end it doesn't matter, you shouldn't rely on the server getting either "complete" or "no data", it can get incomplete data.

Comment: If the peer closes the connection, read() will return -1. ClosedChannelException means you closed it yourself. 'Half the data' is sheer invention on your part. -1